# How do we differentiate $x^2\sin(1/x)$ using the first principle?

Tags: derivatives

How do we differentiate $x^2\sin(1/x)$ using the first principle?

Comment: Well, we do it by using the first principle: $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}{f(x)-f(0)\over x-0}=\dots$$

Comment: see this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176080/can-we-say-fx-is-differentiable-at-x-a-leftrightarrow-fx-is-con/2176103#2176103

Comment: Theorems, in this case, derivation rules are proved so that we can tackle hard problems without refering to "first principles". Probably you could derive this function using the definition of the derivative, but it would be rather messy and may even bring you to prove an ad hoc form of the chain rule. While you're at it, you could rather use "first principles" that are even more basic, and find the derivative using epsilon-delta method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\ \frac{(x+h)^2\sin\left(\frac1{x+h}\right)-x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}h\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\ \ $$

$\left.\right.$

$$=\ \ \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\ \frac{x^2\sin\left(\frac1{x+h}\right)+2xh\sin\left(\frac1{x+h}\right)+h^2\sin\left(\frac1{x+h}\right)-x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}h$$

$\left.\right.$

$$\qquad\ \,=\ \ \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\left[\frac{x^2\sin\left(\frac1{x+h}\right)-x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}h+2x\sin\left(\frac1{x+h}\right)+h\sin\left(\frac1{x+h}\right)\right]$$

$\left.\right.$

$$=\ \ 2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)+x^2\cdot\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac1{x+h}\right)-\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}h\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \ \ \,$$

$\left.\right.$

$$\qquad\quad=\ \ 2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)+x^2\cdot\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\left[\frac2h\cdot\sin\frac12\left(\frac1{x+h}-\frac1x\right)\cos\frac12\left(\frac1{x+h}+\frac1x\right)\right]$$

$\left.\right.$

$$=\ \ 2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)+x^2\cos\left(\frac1x\right)\cdot\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\left[-\frac2h\cdot\sin\left(\frac h{2(x+h)x}\right)\right]\quad\ \ \,$$

$\left.\right.$

$$=\ \ 2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)+x^2\cos\left(\frac1x\right)\cdot\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\left[-\frac2h\cdot\left(\frac h{2(x+h)x}\right)\right]\qquad\ \ \,$$

$\left.\right.$

$$=\ \ 2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)+x^2\cos\left(\frac1x\right)\cdot\left(-\frac1{x^2}\right)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$$

$\left.\right.$

$$=\ \ 2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)-\cos\left(\frac1x\right)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\ \ $$

Comment: How do you motivate your 6th equality, i.e. $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\left[-\frac2h\cdot\sin\left(\frac h{2(x+h)x}\right)\right]?$$