# First principle application in finding derivative of $x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

When we apply limit to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{h}\sin\left(\frac{h}{2(x+h)x}\right)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2180555). I think they are neglecting the higher order terms but why?

As such the first two terms in the expansion would be $$\frac{h}{2(x+h)x} - \frac{1}{3!} \left(\frac{h}{2(x+h)x}\right)^3,$$ cancelling one $h$ we get that the first term tends to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2x^2}$, but the second term has $h^2$ in the numerator and $h^3$ in the denominator so shouldn't it be of the form $\frac{1}{h}$? And so we cannot neglect it as did in the above solution?

Comment: $$
 \frac{1}{h}\times -\frac{1}{{3!}}\left[ {\frac{h}{{2(x + h)x}}} \right]^3  =  - \frac{1}{{3!}}\frac{{h^2 }}{{(2(x + h)x)^3 }} \to  - \frac{1}{{3!}}\frac{0}{{(2x^2 )^3 }} = 0
$$

Comment: Thanks @Gary ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second term doesn't have $h^3$ in the denominator, it has $(x+h)^3$. When $x \neq 0$, this has a nonzero limit as $h$ tends to zero so there is no problem. (Quotient of two convergent sequences where the denominator's limit is nonzero is the quotient of the limits.)